# Sparx Enterprise Architect: BPMN collecting activities from several lane instances

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn

I have several business processes modelled in EA. All have the same lanes, so (as I have seen in some tutorial) I added a generic element and the process lanes all reference via the "partitionElementRef" to the same generic element. (See screen, the lower business process contains a lane Capture, which is linked to the upper "Lanes assigned to Roles").
[image]

How can I query EA that I can collect all activities within the different business processes that refer to the same lane? Such, that I can collect from all business processes all elements with the same lane "Capture"?
A list or a matrix would be perfect as a result.

Comment: With _collect_ you mean query?

Comment: Something like that, yes. The result I need would be a kind of list or matrix (ideally for all lanes), such as: 
"lane A -> Task 1, Task 2" and "lane B -> Task 3, Task 4, Task 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use `Lane` for the generic element, but rather use a BPMN `PartnerRole` or `PartnerEntity` element.
Using lanes would be a BPMN syntax violation.

Apart from that, if you want to query the model to get all lanes and their generic element you can use a query like this

```
select o.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, o.Object_ID as CLASSTYPE, o.Name, o.Stereotype, gen.Name as GenericElement
from ((t_object o 
inner join t_objectproperties tv on (tv.Object_ID = o.Object_ID
                                and tv.Property = 'PartitionElementRef'))
left join t_object gen on gen.ea_guid = tv.Value)
where o.Stereotype = 'Lane'
```

The `Lane` is linked to the *generic element* with the tagged value `PartitionElementRef` which contains the guid of the generic element.

If you want to get the Activities in your lane you join again with `t_object` using the `ParentID`

```
select act.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, act.Object_ID as CLASSTYPE, act.Name, act.Stereotype, 
o.Name as Lane,  gen.Name as GenericElement
from (((t_object o 
inner join t_objectproperties tv on (tv.Object_ID = o.Object_ID
                                and tv.Property = 'PartitionElementRef'))
left join t_object gen on gen.ea_guid = tv.Value)
inner join t_object act on (act.ParentID = o.Object_ID
                        and act.Stereotype = 'Activity'))
where o.Stereotype = 'Lane'
```

Bonus tip: if you leave the name of the lane empty, it will show the name of the *generic* element on the diagram.

Comment: That (nearly) solves the problem  - many thanks. I added the query the does that what I need, it adds at the least "where" statement (for short).

Comment: I've updated the last query to return only result that have activities

Answer (score 0):

Based on Geert Bellekens solution, I simply added the last where clause...

```
select act.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, act.Object_ID as CLASSTYPE, act.Name, act.Stereotype, 
o.Name as Lane,  gen.Name as GenericElement
from (((t_object o 
inner join t_objectproperties tv on (tv.Object_ID = o.Object_ID
                            and tv.Property = 'PartitionElementRef'))
left join t_object gen on gen.ea_guid = tv.Value)
left join t_object act on (act.ParentID = o.Object_ID
                    and act.Stereotype = 'Activity'))
where (o.Stereotype = 'Lane' and act.Stereotype = 'Activity')
```

Finally, in the query result, grouped by Generic Element

Comment: you don't need that `and act.Stereotype = 'Activity'` in the where clause because that is already present in the join condition. If you only want to see results that have Activities you can simply change the `left join` into an `inner join`